# Initializing a pointer to a string

Tags: c, linux, string

I have a very basic doubt. Say I declare a pointer to a string.

```
char *data;
```

and allocate memory as follows

```
data = malloc(13*sizeof(char));
```

My question is how do I initialize the string.
Is

```
data = NULL;
```

the right thing to do.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by initialise? And that's not the right thing to do as you will now have a block of memory allocated but with no pointer to it. Memory leak.

Comment: @Griffin...I had a doubt and hence needed some help from intelligent folks like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by initialize you mean make it all zeroes, then:

```
memset(data, 0, 13);
```

Will do it.

Or, as **@Griffin** said, using [`calloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/) instead of `malloc` to allocate and initialize the area at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialise the string to an empty string then

```
*data = '\0';
```

is the right thing to do. What you did was make your variable point to NULL, instead of the 13 bytes of memory you'd allocated.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want an empty string, `data[0] = '\0'` will do just fine.  Setting `data = NULL` like your example shows will just leak your memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set use **[memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/)**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/free/) function.

Comment: sorry I thought that was a typo. The data = NULL made me think you were trying to free the memory. Yes memset is the way to go. Though that doesn't really accomplish anything. Unless an API or function you were passing `data` to required all 0s or something wierd like that.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, consider the memset / memcpy or strncpy functions. 
With

```
memset(void *b, int c, size_t len);
```

you can initalize the memory area, with memcpy or strncp you can copy over data into the memory area. If you deal with strings you should use strncpy.

Have fun